# Загадочный TAG и способы его применения

Tags: java, android, retrofit, callback

Столкнулся с решением, которое натолкнуло на неожиданный для меня вопрос.
В своём приложении(с помощью retrofit'a 1.9) реализовал загрузку фотографии(из галлереи). Из чего вытекла следующая идея, что пользователь может в любой момент просто отменить загрузку данного фото. Следовательно необходимо было реализовать *Cancel Request*, учитывая что в версии 1.9 это очень *больно*. 
Но и опять же, суть вопроса не в этом, было решено сделать нечто следующее, а именно реализовать интерфейс CancelableCallback:

```
public abstract class CancelableCallback implements Callback<ImageUpload> {

private static List<CancelableCallback> mList = new ArrayList<>();

private boolean isCanceled = false;
private Object mTag = null;

public static void cancelAll() {
    Iterator<CancelableCallback> iterator = mList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next().isCanceled = true;
        iterator.remove();
    }
}

public static void cancel(Object tag) {
    if (tag != null) {
        Iterator<CancelableCallback> iterator = mList.iterator();
        CancelableCallback item;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            item = iterator.next();
            if (tag.equals(item.mTag)) {
                item.isCanceled = true;
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}

public CancelableCallback() {
    mList.add(this);
}

public CancelableCallback(Object tag) {
    mTag = tag;
    mList.add(this);
}

public void cancel() {
    isCanceled = true;
    mList.remove(this);
}

@Override
public final void success(ImageUpload t, Response response) {
    if (!isCanceled)
        onSuccess(t, response);
    mList.remove(this);
}

@Override
public final void failure(RetrofitError error) {
    if (!isCanceled)
        onFailure(error);
    mList.remove(this);
}

public abstract void onSuccess(ImageUpload t, Response response);

public abstract void onFailure(RetrofitError error);
}
```

После чего, реализовать в нашем фрагменте:

```
CancelableCallback.cancel(TAG);
```

И вот собственно говоря вопрос, **TAG** как с ним правильно обращаться и какие способы его применения. Пока мне известно, что Tag – это некое Object-хранилище у каждого View, куда мы можем поместить нужные вам данные(*хотелось бы поподробней*).

Comment: тэг используют для хранения данных либо для поиска по нему в иерархии

Comment: @Алексей Мальченко окей, поправьте меня, если не прав. Вот в коде у меня CancelableCallback.cancel(TAG); мне туда стоит импортировать мои данные или как? не понимаю. + как возможно задействовать эту команду по нажатию на элемент?(то есть нажимаю на любой из 10 скажем элементов и он не загружается)

Comment: Вам нужно настроить связь ImageView и Callback. Заведите Map<Callback, ImageView> связывайте там запрос с ImageView и после выполнения Callback вытаскивайте и обновляйте нужный вам ImageView. Для отмены просто удалите связь. Еще учтите, что на один ImageView есть вероятность создать несколько запросов, это может быть плохо для вас. Не забывайте почистить связи после удаления Activity, а то можете упасть.
Или просто используйте библиотеку Picasso.

Comment: @Алексей Мальченко В проекте используется данная библиотека, но под просто Вы имели в виду наверное более простой способ? Увы с данной библиотекой еще не работал.